# Проблема с запросом к Jersey REST сервису

Tags: java, java-ee, rest, веб-служба, jersey

Пытаюсь написать веб сервис.

При попытке написать REST веб сервис, использую ServletContainer как показанно в коде внизу, получаю ошибку 404!

При попытке написать сервис не используя ServletContainer а унаследование от HttpServlet и переопределение метода doGet сервис работает.

- Почему при использовании SеrvlеtContainer и init param я получаю ошибку 404 ? Что не хватает в данном коде ?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
  <!--  //Подход работает!
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.ServiceTest</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/get</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  -->
  
   <servlet> //Подход не работет!
    
    <servlet-name>Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    
    <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>test</param-value>
    </init-param>  
  
  </servlet>
  
  
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/get</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  
</web-app>
```

```
@Path("/service")//Не работает
public class ServiceTest{


@Path("/get")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getJSON(){

    return "Hello";
}
}


@Path("/service")//Работает
public class ServiceTest extends HttpServlet{

@Path("/get")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter print = resp.getWriter();
    print.print("Hello");
}
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: по идее @Path начинает работать после указанного url сервлета  (/service/get), поэтому попробуй перейти по такой ссылке http://localhost:8080/WebTest/service/get/service/get

Comment: А добавьте аннотацию @GET?